# How can I write my char* pointer to files with always in utf8 format?

Tags: c++, linux, utf-8, locale, ofstream

I'm trying to read some .txt files and then make some tokenize operations on the strings that are in my files, then I wrote them in another files. But after my files written , some of them written with Western (ISO-8859-15) encoding like;

> ÃallÄ± Neyzen Tevfik MÃŒzeyyen Senar MÃŒzeyyen Senar ÃallÄ± Ã¶teden
> dosttular eÅi ErcÃŒment IÅÄ±l ÃallÄ± arkadaÅ idiler Hele annesi
> 1943 vefat ettiÄinde...

But some of them are in their regular format as they read.(Current Locale (UTF-8)).I want all of them in same format.(UTF-8)

My code is this:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <complearn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <locale>
#include <clocale>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


  int fileNum=20;//Number of file wanted to clean

  string fileDir="HU";
  string inputFile=fileDir+"/"+fileDir;//Directory and name of file
  string outputFile=fileDir+"/Out/out";//output/cleaned file name

  string word1,word2,fword;
 
  string frequencyFile="frequencyList.txt";

  ifstream fin2(frequencyFile.c_str(),ios::in);

  locale utf8_locale(locale(), new codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t> ("en_US.UTF-8"));
  locale::global( std::locale("en_US.UTF8") );
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

for (int i=1;i<=fileNum;i++){


  inputFile+=to_string(i)+".txt";
  outputFile+=to_string(i)+".txt";


  ifstream fin1(inputFile.c_str(),ios::in);
  ofstream finNew(outputFile.c_str(),ios::out|ios_base::binary);
  finNew.imbue(utf8_locale);
  

if(fin1.is_open())
  {

    if(fin2.is_open())
                {

        while(fin1 >>  word1)
        {
                    char *token=NULL;//(char*) malloc(sizeof(20*sizeof(int)));
                    char *dup = strdup(word1.c_str());
                    token = strtok(dup, "(&+.,!?*)...;':-)\"\"’“\\/\'");//extract from punctuations
  

                    if(token==nullptr)
                        token=" ";


                while(fin2 >> word2)
                {

                    if(strcmp(token,word2.c_str())==0)//if token is in frequencyfile pass
                            break;
              
                 }

                if(strcmp(token,word2.c_str())!= 0&&token!=nullptr)
                    { 
                                finNew<<  string(token) << " ";//write to my new file

                        
                    }
            fin2.clear();
            fin2.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

            }//fin1 loop                 
            
        }//fin2.close()

  }//fin1.close()
  inputFile=fileDir+"/"+fileDir;//Directory and name of file
  outputFile=fileDir+"/Out/out";
  }//end of for

  return(0);
}
```

I tried to change locale with hoping something can change but nothings change. Please help me what is wrong with this code that cause this problem.

PS: By the way I'm in linux mint/maya platform and I'm compiling my code as in codeblocks.

Comment: What is the encoding of the source files?  Your `ofstream` locale expects `token` to be in a default locale since you are not specifying a source locale for conversions. And why are you using C functions to tokenize and compare your C++ strings? Use [`std::string::find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of), [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), and [`std::string::operator==()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) instead. That also fixes your `strdup()` memory leak.

Comment: Source files are in UTF-8 encoding. And thanks for your advices I may confused about the c and c++ functions. I will try to change my code like you said. But how can I use as token like I wanted to do (remove punctuations) by substr() as your suggested? Could you show me an example?

Comment: If your source files are UTF-8 encoded, then you should not need to imbue a UTF-8 locale into your `ofstream`. The `string` values you read from the input files should already be UTF-8 encoded, so you should be able to write them as-is to your output files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau my input files , they are all in utf8-encoding format I checked it. But I couldn't write them as in UTF-8 encoded to output files, some words are not written correctly. How can I solve this problem? Please check my code again.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Please show the actual data being written.  Also, consider opening the `ifstream` in binary mode, and maybe also use `finNew.write(token, length of token)` instead of `finNew << string(token)`.

Comment: I edited my post with file examples , please check it. And I changed my code as you say but nothing changed: `ifstream fin1(inputFile.c_str(),ios::in|ios_base::binary);//ifstream statement `  `finNew.write(token,strlen(token));//file writing statement`

Comment: I found something, I removed this punctuation ( ’ “) from this statement `token = strtok(dup, "(&+.,!?*)...;':-)\"\"’“\\/\'");` ; and C/3 things are gone. But I have words that like: “Wait etc.  Why this can be happen? And If you realized that I have two different quotes in my strtok function. (" ') and (’ “)-these are that I removed. But I should remove them also from the file. How can I fix this? @RemyLebeau

Comment: yeay! I solved it by your first suggestion: by substr() and find() functions. I extracted these quotes seperately with using this functions. And my problem solved.  My code becomes longer and full of if's but problem solved! Maybe I can find better solutions later but this is enough for me now. Thanks ! @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1):

There is no encoding specified in text files. Whatever bytes you write, are there, and whatever other applications will use, they will interpret it as such. The file is obviously written in UTF-8, only the application you opened it with wrongly detected it as ISO 8859-15.

Comment: Ok then , I am opening them by text editor in linux. So if it just wrong detection , they will not affect my results when I want to use them in another applications.For example Application knows that when it is written like "ÃallÄ±" then it means "Çallı" . Right?

Comment: Yes, if the application knows it is UTF-8 and reads it as such, it will work. Also, in many text editors in Linux, it is possible to tell the text editor which encoding it should use (by default it either tries to autodetect or uses the one set in your locale).

Comment: But I tried to change encoding to UTF-8 in text editor (gedit), I changed it but nothings change in file appearance. What does it mean then? :S (I mean , I'm continuing to see it like "ÃallÄ±...")

Comment: If you change the encoding after the file is opened, it converts it from the encoding it detected to the one you selected. You need to [select UTF-8 when opening the file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/282672/opening-a-non-utf8-encoded-text-file).

Comment: Thanks I tried,now I see somethings better ... But do you know what does it mean, I saw these somewheres of the file more than one :  **\C3**

Comment: That means the file being opened is not UTF-8 encoded to begin with.

Comment: UTF-8 is variable-length encoding and this is one of codes which can only appear in the first byte of a multi-byte code (UTF-8 is self-synchronizing and so it differentiates between first and other bytes in each code). That means the multi-byte code was split or not written entirely, or in other words the rest of its bytes were lost.

Comment: Is this can be from this code : `finNew<<  string(token) << " ";//write to my new file`  trying to write char* pointer string to the file ? @StenSoft